# React Native setState not updating states - javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

I am attempting to use the setState method to update the states, however whenever I execute the function, everything stops once it reaches the setState method.  However, all code up until the function does work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TextInput, ImageBackground, TouchableHighlight, Alert, Dimensions, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import { SelectList } from 'react-native-dropdown-select-list';
import { MultipleSelectList } from 'react-native-dropdown-select-list';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const App = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");
  
  
  const data = [
      {key:'1', value:'Mobiles', disabled:true},
      {key:'2', value:'Appliances'},
      {key:'3', value:'Cameras'},
      {key:'4', value:'Computers', disabled:true},
      {key:'5', value:'Vegetables'},
      {key:'6', value:'Diary Products'},
      {key:'7', value:'Drinks'},
  ]

  let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  const state = {
        titleScreen: 'block',
        createAccountScreen: 'none',
        hubScreen: 'none',
        deliveryScreen: 'none',
        notesScreen: 'none',
        tutoringScreen: 'none',
        profileScreen: 'none',
        usernameLogin: '',
        passwordLogin: '',
        initialState: 0,
    }
loggedIn = () => {
        console.log('Test 1')
        this.setState({
          titleScreen: 'none',
          createAccountScreen: 'block',
          hubScreen: 'none',
          deliveryScreen: 'none',
          notesScreen: 'none',
          tutoringScreen: 'none',
          profileScreen: 'none',
        })
        console.log('Test 2');
        
    }
```

I researched possible solutions online and attempted to use arrow functions, however that did not solve my problem.  I also logged phrases to the console to see if anything was happening when the function was called, and found that the function stopped as soon as it passed the method.

Comment: What is `this.setState` supposed to be?  It looks like you're mixing older class-based React components with newer function-based ones.  Your state setter is called `setSelected` here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse classes and functions in React Native.
In your example, you are using `React.useState` (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp)) and `setState` (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp)). Both do the same thing, but in different ways.

You could correct your code like this:

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState({
  titleScreen: 'block',
  createAccountScreen: 'none',
  hubScreen: 'none',
  deliveryScreen: 'none',
  notesScreen: 'none',
  tutoringScreen: 'none',
  profileScreen: 'none',
  usernameLogin: '',
  passwordLogin: '',
  initialState: 0
 });
```

And then, your `loggedIn` function:

```
loggedIn = () => {
  console.log('Test 1')
  setSelected({
    titleScreen: 'none',
    createAccountScreen: 'block',
    hubScreen: 'none',
    deliveryScreen: 'none',
    notesScreen: 'none',
    tutoringScreen: 'none',
    profileScreen: 'none',
  })
  console.log('Test 2');
}
```

In this situation, your `state` variable is useless. After using the `setSelected` function, you can access the variable by using `selected`.

I'm not 100% sure this answers your question, but I hope it will at least give you info on how to use states in React :)

Comment: I made your changes to my program, and am still having issues.  Could it possibly be in how I am calling the method?  I am currently stating: <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => loggedIn}
          >

Comment: This is also wrong, it should be setSelected not this.setSelected

Comment: @Bowis you are right, I corrected my answer.

Comment: @LiamMorley you should use either `onPress={() => loggedIn()}` or `onPress={loggedIn}`. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches)